# react-redux-react-router v4 url, updates but the component does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

First off, I have read through just about every example I can find and looked through various boilerplates to see how others have done this. I am having issues loading pages when clicking `<Link>`'s with react-router v4. I have also installed the package react-router-connected and have been trying that out as well but no improvement can be seen (however it shows the changes in the redux-logger which is nice).

Currently, the url updates just fine and if I manually change the url and press enter, then the next page will load. But, it will not redirect if I click a link. I am also using create-react app for the project, just for your reference. My actual app is setup as the exact example from `usage with react-router` in the official redux docs. For simplicity, I have changed my routes to only include links to basic components that do nothing but redirect to one another.

Root.js which houses my routes

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router'
// import App from './App';
import NewComponent from './NewComponent';
import OldComponentent from './OldComponent';

const Root = ({ store, history }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' component={OldComponentent}/>
          <Route path='/new' component={NewComponent}/>
          {/* <Route path='/' component={App}/>
          <Route path='/:filter' component={App}/> */}
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
)

export default Root;
```

Home component

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

class OldComponent extends React.Component {
  redirectPage = () => { this.props.dispatch(push('/new')); };
  redirectPage1 = () => { this.props.dispatch(push('/')); };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        OLD COMPONENT
        <Button onClick={this.redirectPage}>Redirect new</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.redirectPage1}>Redirect /</Button>
        <Link to='/new'>Redirect Link</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect()(OldComponent));
```

Other basic component for redirection purposes

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

class NewComponent extends React.Component {
  redirectPage = () => { this.props.dispatch(push('/')); };
  redirectPage1 = () => { this.props.dispatch(push('/new')); };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        NEW COMPONENT
        <Button onClick={this.redirectPage}>Redirect /</Button>
        <Button onClick={this.redirectPage1}>Redirect new</Button>
        <Link to='/new'>Redirect Link</Link>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(connect()(NewComponent));
```

As you can see, they are essentially the same component with minor differences. The url will change to `/new or /` and will also update the pathname found in the @@router/LOCATION-CHANGE state objects created by react-router-connected package. The url will also change by clicking the `<Link>` tag but with no redirect.

Any help on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi have you tried using props.history instead of using props.dispatch? I'm new to Reactor Router 4, but our app is using props.history.push('/someRoute').

Comment: I can't believe it... It worked... so simple. Thank you so much. I will post your answer as a solution after I try this out in a more robust example.

Answer (score 0):

The comment posted by @Supertopoz works `this.props.history.push('/pathname')` works. However, after setting that up, the `<Link>` now works as well. I am also using `withRouter` (which I was before) throughout, so that was another important factor in egtting it to work.